# Update m-to-m relationship, duplicate primary key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-6

i am trying to update a m-to-m relation with a ListBox. My entity-model looks like this:

[image]

I have a ListBox with Checkboxes where the user can decide which Player is in the league and which is not (IsSelected-Property). There are two problems: At first i can't check and then uncheck a Player (it won't be deleted). Second Problem: the first try, everything works and when i do the selection again, i get the following exception:

> - _innerException {"An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details."}  System.Exception {System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException}
> - _innerException {"Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PLID'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.PlayerLeague'. The duplicate key value is (2, 2).\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}  System.Exception {System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException}

```
using (BettingLeagueEntities entities = new BettingLeagueEntities())
{
    foreach (PlayerCheckBoxList p in this.PlayerList)
    {
        if(p.IsSelected == true)
        {
            PlayerLeague pl = new PlayerLeague();
            pl.League = this.ActiveLeague;
            pl.Player = p.ActivePlayer;

            var local = entities.Set<Player>().Local.FirstOrDefault(x => x.PID == p.ActivePlayer.PID);
            if(local != null)
            {
                entities.Entry(local).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Detached;
            }

            var localLeague = entities.Set<League>().Local.FirstOrDefault(x => x.LID == this.ActiveLeague.LID);
            if (localLeague != null)
            {
                entities.Entry(localLeague).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Detached;
            }

            if (entities.Entry(p.ActivePlayer).State == System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Detached)
            {
                entities.Player.Add(p.ActivePlayer);
                entities.Entry(p.ActivePlayer).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
            }
            if (entities.Entry(this.ActiveLeague).State == System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Detached)
            {
                entities.League.Add(this.ActiveLeague);
                entities.Entry(this.ActiveLeague).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
            }

            if(p.ActivePlayer.PlayerLeague.All(x => x.LID != this.ActiveLeague.LID))
            {
                p.ActivePlayer.PlayerLeague.Add(pl);
                this.ActiveLeague.PlayerLeague.Add(pl);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            PlayerLeague local = entities.Set<PlayerLeague>().Local.FirstOrDefault(x => x.LID == this.ActiveLeague.LID && x.PID == p.ActivePlayer.PID);
            if(local != null)
            {
                entities.PlayerLeague.Attach(local);
                entities.PlayerLeague.Remove(local);
            }

            entities.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    entities.SaveChanges();
}
```

I have no clue how to solve this, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: The deselection part is in the else statement where i try to remove the PlayerLeague with the specified LID and PID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have it! I tried to comment a little bit to make it understandable.

The first problem was that i checked if my PlayerLeague already exists too lately. I moved this condition in my first if(statement).

The second error was, that in my else block, my statement to find a playerleague returned alsways null. Now i check if there is any entity and if this is true, i delete it.

```
using (BettingLeagueEntities entities = new BettingLeagueEntities())
{
    foreach (PlayerCheckBoxList p in this.PlayerList)
    {
        // Check if the Player is seleceted and if the ActivePlayer has the Active League
        if (p.IsSelected == true && p.ActivePlayer.PlayerLeague.All(x => x.LID != this.ActiveLeague.LID))
        {
            // Define the new PlayerLeague
            PlayerLeague pl = new PlayerLeague {PID = p.ActivePlayer.PID, LID = this.ActiveLeague.LID};

            var localPlayer = entities.Set<Player>().Local.FirstOrDefault(x => x.PID == p.ActivePlayer.PID);

            if (localPlayer != null)
            {
                entities.Entry(localPlayer).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Detached;
            }

            if (entities.Entry(p.ActivePlayer).State == System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Detached)
            {
                entities.Player.Add(p.ActivePlayer);
                entities.Entry(p.ActivePlayer).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
            }

            var localLeague = entities.Set<League>().Local.FirstOrDefault(x => x.LID == this.ActiveLeague.LID);

            if (localLeague != null)
            {
                entities.Entry(localLeague).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Detached;
            }

            if (entities.Entry(this.ActiveLeague).State == System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Detached)
            {
                entities.League.Add(this.ActiveLeague);
                entities.Entry(this.ActiveLeague).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
            }

            p.ActivePlayer.PlayerLeague.Add(pl);
            this.ActiveLeague.PlayerLeague.Add(pl);
        }
        else
        {
            // Check if there is a PlayerLeague for this Player and league
            bool hasPlayerLeague =
                entities.PlayerLeague.Any(x => x.LID == this.ActiveLeague.LID && x.PID == p.ActivePlayer.PID);

            if (hasPlayerLeague && p.IsSelected == false)
            {
                // Find PlayerLeague
                PlayerLeague pl =
                        entities.PlayerLeague.FirstOrDefault(
                        x => x.LID == this.ActiveLeague.LID && x.PID == p.ActivePlayer.PID);

                // Attach and Remove PlayerLeague
                entities.PlayerLeague.Attach(pl);
                entities.PlayerLeague.Remove(pl);
            }

            entities.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Humans are not very good at spotting small differences in two blocks of code. Perhaps it would be more useful to others with a similar issue if you summarize what you found the problem to be and what the solution entailed.